# Print String in Python

Tags: python, string

I tried running this basic python script to print something, and it doesn't seem to be executing properly.

```py
name = "Tyler";
print{name};
```

I am getting this error:

```
File "C:\Users\tyler\main.py", line 2
    print{name};
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
```

I tried changing line 2 to:

```
print(...)
```

but it prints out
`Ellipsis`, not my name.

Comment: Have you tried `print(name)`? The `print(...)` suggestion in the error-message is just a suggestion for how you could possibly fix the problem.

Comment: function call are with this templated function ( args), when you want to print : print(name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need semicolons in Python
The issue was the use of curly braces. Call your variable `name` with `print()` like this:

```py
name = "Tyler"
print(name)
```